# Is this value of critical Reynolds number also valid for ducts?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, convection

In internal flow, when a fluid flows inside a circular pipe, the most practical value of critical Reynolds number is taken as 2300. I was wondering if this number is also the same for non circular ducts? Does the critical Reynolds number of a duct will also be around 2300 for most practical cases?

Comment: The transition range is normally taken as 1700 to 2300 but laminar flow has been found outside these values under controlled conditions.

Comment: There are relatively simple scaling laws for arbitrary polygon shapes. Here's a paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264496985_Fully_developed_turbulent_flow_pressure_drop_in_circular_and_noncircular_ducts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, if a flow has a different geometry, such as flow in a square duct, or over a turbine blade, transition will occur at different values of Re.

Additionally another very important point is that in circular tube:

- if the flow is undisturbed (i.e. very smooth pipe walls) then the transition to transient flow is at much greater Re numbers
- if Re is less than 2000, then the flow will **always be laminar** even when it is disturbed.

Comment: That was useful.